# How do i take a user's message as a variable?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot where I made prefix as "!e" and after that I wanted it to be a variable of anything...

How do I do that?

```
    client.on("message", (message) => {
        var botmessage = usermessage
        if (message.content === `${prefix} ${usermessage}`) { 
            var usermessage = botmessage
        message.channel.send(`:${botmessage}:`)
        } 
        
    })
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It doesn't really make sense at the moment. What does _"after a space I wanted it to be a variable of anything"_ mean?

Comment: the space i meant is leaving a gap between the prefix and the message

Comment: `var usermessage=message.content.substr(2)` would have everything of the string except the initial 3 characters

Comment: so will it work? (let me try it out)

Comment: the answer demonstrates what i mean

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: you're running a discord bot.. i the response should be seen when you talk to the bot ON discord.. im not logging anything to the console

Comment: ... and this is exactly the reason I asked you to rephrase the question. Looking at your code doesn't help me either to understand what you want to achieve. I'm voting to close this.

Comment: @Nigelrex go in a server ur bot can type and say `!e asdf` and the bot will reply `whatever` meaning my code works.. if it does, can u please mark?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is `substr` logic

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('!e ')) { 
        var usermessage = message.content.substr(3)
        var botmessage="whatever"
        message.channel.send(`:${botmessage}:`)
    }
})
```

Comment: It should be `.substr(3)` if you also want to remove the space between the command and the rest of the string. Or `.substr(2).trim()`.